# Does gauge size of a signal wire has an effect to its susseptability to electromagnetic interference?

Tags: inductor, interference, gauge, electromagnetic

Let's say you have the option to use a lower gauge wire size (i.e. thicker wire) for a signal wire that happens to be run along power wires. Will it pick up more electromagnetic interference than using a "normal" size wire for that application? And i'm not talking about high frequency signals, or other signals that require shielding. Just a genuine physics based question which i suspect it has to do with the magnetic flux passing through the conductor which in this case it will have more surface area exposed and therefore it will be more susceptible to an emf..Am i right? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the diameter of the wire has no significant effect on its EMC characteristics.

It isn't a question of surface area, but rather just whether or not a conductive path exists at all.

Answer (score 2):

For electro-static interference. (which includes changing E-fields to ~100kHz range, or so) the pick up can depend on the capacitance which goes as the area, proportional to the diameter for a wire.  (You make thin traces on a pcb to limit capacitive pickup.)

edit: as long as the length of the wire is less than ~1/10 the wavelength.